# How to make optimal decision in poker like single player card game?

Tags: javascript, probability, combinatorics, playing-cards

I need some help to finish my app that helps to make optimal decision in card game.

Short game description:

- Single player game - 1 player one deck only for himself
- 24 card deck, card values from 1 to 8, 3 colors of each (Red,Yellow, Blue).

At start of the game deck gets randomly shuffled then player pulls 5 cards (19 left in deck) to his hand and from this point he's allowed to:

- Put away one card (this card is not in game anylonger) and take one card from top of shuffled deck for its place.
  or
- Can put away 3 cards that form a one of possible point granting combinations, then takes 3 cards to his hand.

Game ends when cards in deck ends and player have no more possible scoring combinations.

Goal of the game is to obtain as much points as possible.

List of variants: (called later combinations)
Three of a kind (8 possible in total):

- 111 - 20 points
- 222 - 30 points
- 333 - 40 points
- 444 - 50 points
- 555 - 60 points
- 666 - 70 points
- 777 - 80 points
- 888 - 90 points

Straight (card can have any color, 144 possible in total):

- 123 - 10 points
- 234 - 20 points
- 345 - 30 points
- 456 - 40 points
- 567 - 50 points
- 678 - 60 points

Straight flush (cards have to be in the same color, RRR/YYY/BBB, 18 possible in total):

- 123 - 50 points
- 234 - 60 points
- 345 - 70 points
- 456 - 80 points
- 567 - 90 points
- 678 - 100 points

I created the whole game logic in JS but suffer to make algoritm that will help me:

- which card to put away from hand? - to get highest chance for combination
  or:
- which card to put away from hand?- to lose least amount of possible combinations

I don't really know which approach i should take. Or should i combine them somehow and let the formula decide? Currently I'm reading about risk reward ratio maybe thats the way to go?

I have to remember that with each card less i have less and less possible combinations (starting with 170), but sometimes its worth in later stage of the game to sacrifice cheaper combination for higher point score.

My past ways of thinking:

1. Calculate the probability of each possible remaining combination when putting away each card from hand.(i.e. 5 times) and decide which one is the worst.
2. Calculate the probability of each possible remaining combination for every 2 card subset of 5 card set in hand (so 10 times looking for 1 card to fill the combination) and decide which card from hand is the worst.
3. Calculate the probability of each possible remaining combination left in deck (not counting cards in hand there). 3+ moves in advance

And somehow add those three together to get optimal/close to optimal solution?

Should i add potential loss to my calculations and how to form them? If i take weak combination and later in the game i can not obtain higher ones since they are mutually exclusive.

Comment: I suggest you try something and see how it works out.

Comment: since this isn't really a question about a  piece of broken code but rather how to design a piece of program logic, it may be better to ask the question at one of the other stack exchange sites;  perhaps the people at the math site can help with the mathematic formulas, or the people at the poker site can help with calculating probabilities?

Comment: I did the 1st and 2nd. from past ways of thinking segment.
From my observation they too often force single combination costing them a lot of points.
On average I score more points than these two scripts 
In my opinion solely becouse they don't take into account to sacrifice some combinations.
I also calculated the each possible remaining combination left in deck not counting cards in hand there but have no clue how to combine the results.